# iTunes cannot run because some of its required files are missing

Tags: itunes, windows

Today I checked for iTunes updates (I was actually looking for IOS 15 for my iPhone) and it asked to update iTunes to the latest release (12.12.0.6).

After the update, I got this error message when starting iTunes:

[image: iTunes cannot run because some of its required files are missing. Please reinstall iTunes.]

I tried to repair the installation. No luck.
I uninstalled and reinstalled iTunes. Same error.
I uninstalled all Apple software as documented [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204275), rebooted and reinstalled iTunes. Same result.
I uninstalled everything again and tried to install the version of iTunes distributed by the Microsoft Store (which I usually avoid). Even that doesn't work, same error message again.

OS is Windows 10 x64 21H1 with latest updates.

iTunes was running fine before the update.

---

### Update

I tried installing iTunes on a fresh Windows VM which I had lying around (same OS release and updates, no other software installed), which *never* had any iTunes version installed or used on it.
I still received the same error and iTunes doesn't start.
This looks definitely like a seriously buggy release.

Comment: Tho I have not seen this specific error with iTunes, you have reached the point where you uninstall *all* Apple software from the PC. Copy your iTunes library folder to a safe place (EG back it up) and remove all folders that have anything to do with iTunes, Apple, bonjour, etc. Delete the **contents** of the Windows\Temp folder and the **contents** of Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\temp. And if you know how any remnants of Apple/iTunes in the registry. reboot and reinstall.

Comment: See update. This release of iTunes for Windows doesn't seem to work *at all*.

Comment: The problem seems to be widespread: https://discussions.apple.com/community/itunes/itunes_for_windows.

Comment: My team tested this on several computers and it turns out that the majority of installs fail (4 OK vs. 7 fails) (both classic iTunes and MS Store) but not all, which leads me to some environment issue, not a fully faulty installer.

Comment: @Massimo UPDATE: It looks like it works when the Windows user interface is in English and breaks when you use another language system language.

Comment: @8ctopus Confirmed, it works on English-language systems, but not in Italian-language ones, even when setting all regional settings to English. Looks like the Windows UI language is the culprit.

Comment: I just reported this bug in the Apple discussion forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253164287.

Comment: Bug reports to Apple should be sent via the feedback channels listed at the bottom of apple.com, not via their forum.

Comment: @nohillside Reported it to Apple support too.

Comment: I have the same problem but I am already using an English language UI (UK).


iTunes worked fine yesterday. Windows did some kind of update when I booted-up this morning (I had the "There are a few more things we need to setup..." window when I logged-in). Now iTunes no longer works.


iTunes is installed via the Windows Store. I presume it was updated automatically as part of whatever other update Windows was doing this morning.


And just to repeat, my Windows display language is and always has been set to "English (United Kingdom)". It is the only language I have installed.

Comment: @thoughton the bug affects all Windows version which are not in "en-US" language. Yes, all other English variants like "en-UK" are affected too. Only "en-US" works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I confirm that changing the windows user interface to english, then magically itunes works without any problems.
no need to reinstall or repair.

Tried it in on different PC's, Windows Versions, Networks, fresh install, update, repair, clean deinstall and reinstall etc. all in German, never got it to start up.

Now in english -> first try, iTunes works!
Crazy bug.

**UPDATE:**

Today i got the iTunes Version 12.12.1.1 Update, after Installing it, iTunes is now working again.

Comment: Confirmed, it works on English-language systems, but not in Italian-language ones (and it looks like in German-language ones too), even when setting all regional settings to English. Looks like the Windows UI language is the culprit.

Comment: I just reported this bug in the Apple discussion forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253164287.

Comment: Sounds like the translation file is missing :-/

Comment: Addendum: the bug affects all Windows version which are not in "en-US" language. Yes, all other English variants like "en-UK" are affected too. Only "en-US" works.

Comment: Apple just released UWP iTunes 12.12.1.1, classic version not yet available.

Comment: 12.12.1.1 is now working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I installed iTunes for the first time in a Windows 11 VM (22000.194) and it installed and opened fine, I then installed it on my main Windows 10 21H1 machine (never been installed before) and it launched fine, I launched it a few times to be sure. Could Apple have replaced the bad installer already?

[image: on Windows 10 x64 21H1]

Comment: Same error for me, both with the Apple installer and the Microsoft Store app; I tested it today on a fresh VM with no prior iTunes exposure.
But I'm using Windows 10, not 11.

Comment: The screenshot shows install success on Windows 10. I installed in main machine (Windows 10) and Windows 11 VM, both worked.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue on two PC's, on Windows 11 and Windows 10. This update was automatically pushed by Microsoft Store and is faulty, floored or corrupt. If it's not working across multiple platforms (Apple, Microsoft) then it's obviously the update at fault from Apple, not specific user settings for every iTunes customer in the world....

Comment: After seeing it failing in the same way on another Windows VM (with no prior iTunes installation), I tend to agree.

Answer (score -2):

Resolvi meu problema com esse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7SpJBd-uIU

Translation: "I resolved my problem with this video"

Comment: Can you please post an answer in english and also summarize the points made in the video? This ensures that the answer stays useful in case the video gets removed.

Comment: This is useless. I have no problems uninstalling iTunes, and the linked tool doesn't find anything Apple-related in the list of installed programs. Also, I tried installing iTunes on a clean VM, with the same result.